# Claim: Cat litter with different colors each son, could have different fathers

Tags: reproduction

I'm newbie in biology. I can't look this in the internet and distinguish reliable sources because of this. I want to know if it's normal that a cat mother [litter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litter_(animal)) normally has multiple fathers, and that is the cause of cats looking very differently colored. Now, I imagine difference in coloring of the [fur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fur) could happen with the same father, because sons are not necessarily genetically identical, however there are many claims in google when searching:

> http://pets.thenest.com/can-cats-litter-two-different-fathers-8341.html
>
> http://pets.thenest.com/possible-kittens-one-father-8061.html
>
> http://www.drjeffnichol.com/?p=2277
>
> http://animalcarebasics.com/each-kitten-different-father/

If the claim is true, does all the kids start developing at different starting times? Does that mean they could be born some more premature than others? How big is the window for female cats to be fecundated?

Comment: This might be better suited to [skeptics.se].

Comment: @MattDMo I though the same. I decided randomly.